# DSolve fails to handle summation involving DiracDelta

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, symbolic, summation, generalized-function

Executing

```
s = DSolve[{y''[x] + y[x]==Sum[DiracDelta[x-2^n]/2^n,{n,0,Infinity}],y[-Pi/2]==-1,y'[-Pi/2]== 0}, y[x], x]
```

, I obtained `{}`, i.e. no solution. However, I think the solution exists. Here are my arguments.

Let us consider the above problem, replacing the series in the RHS of the ODE under consideration by a finite sum:

```
r = DSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] == Sum[DiracDelta[x - 2^n]/2^n, {n, 0, k}], 
y[-Pi/2] == -1, y'[-Pi/2] == 0}, y[x], x, Assumptions -> k > 1] //Activate
```

> $$\left\{\left\{y(x)\to -\cos (x) \int_1^{-\frac{\pi }{2}} -\sin (K[1]) \sum _{n=0}^k 2^{-n} \delta \left(K[1]-2^n\right) \, dK[1]+\cos (x) \int_1^x -\sin (K[1]) \sum _{n=0}^k 2^{-n} \delta \left(K[1]-2^n\right) \, dK[1]-\sin (x) \left(\int_1^{-\frac{\pi }{2}} \cos (K[2]) \sum _{n=0}^k 2^{-n} \delta \left(K[2]-2^n\right) \, dK[2]\right)+\sin (x) \left(\int_1^x \cos (K[2]) \sum _{n=0}^k 2^{-n} \delta \left(K[2]-2^n\right) \, dK[2]\right)+\sin (x)\right\}\right\} $$

Up to W. Rudin, Functional Analysis, McGRAW-HILL,NewYork-...-Toronto,1973, Ch.6, point 6.16, the finite sum in the integrands converges to the certain distribution in the weak* topology as $k$ approaches infinity. Also

```
Infinity > 1
(*True*)
```

In view of it, (The execution of the code below  takes some time.)

```
s = r /. k -> Infinity;
N[(y[x] /. s) /. x -> 1.1]
(*{0.891207}*)
```

Amn't I right? Opinions and suggestions of Mathematica users are welcome.

Addition. Unfortunately,the result of

```
t = NDSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] == 
 Sum[DiracDelta[x - 2^n]/2^n, {n, 0, 200}], y[-Pi/2] == -1, 
y'[-Pi/2] == 0}, y[x], {x, -2, 3}];(y[x] /. t) /. x -> 1.1
(*{0.991039}*)
```

substantially differs from `{0.891207}`.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: No. I am sure: their supports $\{2^n: n\in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{1\}$ and $\{1\}$ differ. I will be waiting for  serious replies. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I corrected my comment and solution is: `f[x_] := Sin[x] + 
  NSum[-2^-n HeavisideTheta[-2^n + x] Sin[2^n - x], {n, 0, 
    Infinity}]; f[11/10]`

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: Thank you for your comment. `Sum` instead of `NSum` in your code  produces ` Sin[1/10] + Sin[11/10]==0.991041` . Why   is that  modified  ` f[x_] `  a solution of the problem under consideration? The second derivative of `HeavisideTheta` is the derivative od `DiracDelta`.

Comment: Yes I mean `y[x]` not `f[x]`, my mistake.

Comment: [CASE:4545455] has been submitted by me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the concept of `greenfunction` you might find a solution:

**update**

The homogenous solution of your ode is `Sin[x]` which fullfills the initial conditions! 
To calculate `reenfunction` first solve (homogenous initial conditions!)

```
Y = DSolveValue[{y''[x] + y[x] == DiracDelta[x - ξ] , 
y[-Pi/2] == 0, y'[-Pi/2] == 0}, y[x], x] ;
G = Function[{x, ξ}, Evaluate[Y] ]  (*greenfunction*)

Plot3D[G[x, ξ], {x, -Pi/2, 10 Pi}, {ξ, -Pi/2, 10 Pi},MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotLabel -> "Greenfunction",AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The solution of your problem follows to

```
Sin[x]+Sum[G[x, 2^n]/2^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

which , unfortunately, can't be evaluated by Mathematica.

But the finite sums seem to converge

```
Plot[{Sin[x]+Sum[G[x, 2^n]/2^n, {n, 0, 10}]}, {x, -Pi/2, 5 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {x, "y[x]"}]
```

[image]

`y[1.1]` evaluates to

```
Sin[x] + Sum[G[x, 2^n]/2^n, {n, 0, 10}] /. x -> 1.1
(*0.991041*)
```

Comment: First, all that is built on the sand. Second, `NSum[G[1.1, 2^n]/2^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]` produces `1.88225` which is not in accordance with my numeric result `0.891207`.  I will be waiting for serious replies.Thank you anyway.

Comment: In fact, `GreenFunction[]` is built-in, but unfortunately it seems to not be able to do anything here.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: The function `y[x_]:=Sin[x]` is a solution of the corresponding  homogeneous  ODE  `y''[x]+y[x]==0` , not the equation under consideration.

Comment: `Greensfunction` is a well known concept to solve differential equations, not a "sandcastle".   Which solution is the correct one should be shown mathematical.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Unfortunately, `GreenFunction[{u''[x] + u[x], u[-Pi/2] == 1, u'[-Pi/2] == 0}, 
 u[x], {x, -Pi/2, \[Infinity]}, y]` returns the input.

Comment: @user64494 That's why I calculated the Greenfunction directly!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: The result of  `NSum[G[1.1, 2^n]/2^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]` disagrees with both `0.991039` and `0.891207`.

Comment: @user64494 See my updated answer, with corrected initial conditions!

Comment: +1. I find your result more preferable than the numeric solution and accept it.

Comment: Thanks, very promising question! (couldn't find the positive sign in "+1" )

Answer (score 5):

Return to the original problem:

```
s = DSolve[{y''[x] + y[x]==Sum[DiracDelta[x-2^n]/2^n,{n,0,Infinity}],y[-Pi/2]==-1,y'[-Pi/2]== 0}, y[x], x]
```

According to the Mathematica documentation, this is a piecewise homogeneous differential equation with a special inhomogeneity.

This is solved by a linear combination of the trigonometric function fitted to the boundary condition. There are no boundary conditions given in the problem, so just the general linear combination is the solution. This might too be a complex domain problem.

The inhomogeneity is an infinite sum over delta functions. There is an example in the Mathematica documentation on how in principle such a second-order inhomogeneous differential equation is solved.

The solution is some [Ulrich Neumann](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53677/ulrich-neumann). But the problem is the treatment of the infinity series of impulses given to the oscillator.

I was able to reproduce the finite series solution by Mathematica DSolve.

```
r = DSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] == Sum[DiracDelta[x - 2^n]/2^n, {n, 0, k}], 
    y[-Pi/2] == -1, y'[-Pi/2] == 0}, y[x], x, Assumptions -> k > 1] //
   Activate
```

[image: Output]

Which of the two attempts is true for solving the problem.

(i) A finite series step is for sure nice and both work with one.
(ii) the Dirac delta contributes if the argument is zero. That is, in this case, the series 2^n, 1, 2, 4, 8, 18, ... so one. The delta function take in this case the value one. In the given series the next impulse is the half of the one before.
(iii) There is no damping in the differential equation. All impulses are positive.
(iv) The sum over the 1/2^n converges to 2 if the indices start at 0 and go to infinite.
(v) Mathematica solution is a Green's function adapted for the given problem.
(vi) The solutions converge and the problem can be solved the intended path given in the question.
(vii) Mathematica does not solve the infinite series due to convention and not in error.

The problem is run really fast if k is not in the Assumption but given as Integer.

```
r = DSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] == Sum[DiracDelta[x - 2^n]/2^n, {n, 0, 1}], 
   y[-Pi/2] == -1, y'[-Pi/2] == 0}, y[x], x]

{{y[x] -> 
   1/2 (-2 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] Sin[1] - 
      Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] Sin[2] + 2 Sin[x] + 
      Cos[2] HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] Sin[x] + 
      2 Cos[1] HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] Sin[x])}}

Plot[1/2 (-2 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] Sin[1] - 
    Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] Sin[2] + 2 Sin[x] + 
    Cos[2] HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] Sin[x] + 
    2 Cos[1] HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] Sin[x]), {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

[image: Output]

```
r10 = DSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] == 
    Sum[DiracDelta[x - 2^n]/2^n, {n, 0, 10}], y[-Pi/2] == -1, 
   y'[-Pi/2] == 0}, y[x], x]

{{y[x] -> (1/
   1024)(-1024 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] Sin[1] - 
     512 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] Sin[2] - 
     256 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-4 + x] Sin[4] - 
     128 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-8 + x] Sin[8] - 
     64 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-16 + x] Sin[16] - 
     32 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-32 + x] Sin[32] - 
     16 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-64 + x] Sin[64] - 
     8 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-128 + x] Sin[128] - 
     4 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-256 + x] Sin[256] - 
     2 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-512 + x] Sin[512] - 
     Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-1024 + x] Sin[1024] + 1024 Sin[x] + 
     Cos[1024] HeavisideTheta[-1024 + x] Sin[x] + 
     2 Cos[512] HeavisideTheta[-512 + x] Sin[x] + 
     4 Cos[256] HeavisideTheta[-256 + x] Sin[x] + 
     8 Cos[128] HeavisideTheta[-128 + x] Sin[x] + 
     16 Cos[64] HeavisideTheta[-64 + x] Sin[x] + 
     32 Cos[32] HeavisideTheta[-32 + x] Sin[x] + 
     64 Cos[16] HeavisideTheta[-16 + x] Sin[x] + 
     128 Cos[8] HeavisideTheta[-8 + x] Sin[x] + 
     256 Cos[4] HeavisideTheta[-4 + x] Sin[x] + 
     512 Cos[2] HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] Sin[x] + 
     1024 Cos[1] HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] Sin[x])}}

Plot[1/1024 (-1024 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] Sin[1] - 
    512 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] Sin[2] - 
    256 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-4 + x] Sin[4] - 
    128 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-8 + x] Sin[8] - 
    64 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-16 + x] Sin[16] - 
    32 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-32 + x] Sin[32] - 
    16 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-64 + x] Sin[64] - 
    8 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-128 + x] Sin[128] - 
    4 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-256 + x] Sin[256] - 
    2 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-512 + x] Sin[512] - 
    Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-1024 + x] Sin[1024] + 1024 Sin[x] + 
    Cos[1024] HeavisideTheta[-1024 + x] Sin[x] + 
    2 Cos[512] HeavisideTheta[-512 + x] Sin[x] + 
    4 Cos[256] HeavisideTheta[-256 + x] Sin[x] + 
    8 Cos[128] HeavisideTheta[-128 + x] Sin[x] + 
    16 Cos[64] HeavisideTheta[-64 + x] Sin[x] + 
    32 Cos[32] HeavisideTheta[-32 + x] Sin[x] + 
    64 Cos[16] HeavisideTheta[-16 + x] Sin[x] + 
    128 Cos[8] HeavisideTheta[-8 + x] Sin[x] + 
    256 Cos[4] HeavisideTheta[-4 + x] Sin[x] + 
    512 Cos[2] HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] Sin[x] + 
    1024 Cos[1] HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] Sin[x]), {x, -10 \[Pi], 
  10 \[Pi]}]
```

[image: Output]

On the smaller interval:
[image: Output]

The difference between the two solutions is already really small.

```
Plot[{1/2 (-2 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] Sin[1] - 
     Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] Sin[2] + 2 Sin[x] + 
     Cos[2] HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] Sin[x] + 
     2 Cos[1] HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] Sin[x]), 
  1/1024 (-1024 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] Sin[1] - 
     512 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] Sin[2] - 
     256 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-4 + x] Sin[4] - 
     128 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-8 + x] Sin[8] - 
     64 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-16 + x] Sin[16] - 
     32 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-32 + x] Sin[32] - 
     16 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-64 + x] Sin[64] - 
     8 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-128 + x] Sin[128] - 
     4 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-256 + x] Sin[256] - 
     2 Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-512 + x] Sin[512] - 
     Cos[x] HeavisideTheta[-1024 + x] Sin[1024] + 1024 Sin[x] + 
     Cos[1024] HeavisideTheta[-1024 + x] Sin[x] + 
     2 Cos[512] HeavisideTheta[-512 + x] Sin[x] + 
     4 Cos[256] HeavisideTheta[-256 + x] Sin[x] + 
     8 Cos[128] HeavisideTheta[-128 + x] Sin[x] + 
     16 Cos[64] HeavisideTheta[-64 + x] Sin[x] + 
     32 Cos[32] HeavisideTheta[-32 + x] Sin[x] + 
     64 Cos[16] HeavisideTheta[-16 + x] Sin[x] + 
     128 Cos[8] HeavisideTheta[-8 + x] Sin[x] + 
     256 Cos[4] HeavisideTheta[-4 + x] Sin[x] + 
     512 Cos[2] HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] Sin[x] + 
     1024 Cos[1] HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] Sin[x])}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

[image: Output]
The solution match the boundary conditions very well.

If all Heavyside functions contribute the plot looks:

[image: Output]

This is already chaos.

The reason is clear from the Mathematica documentation for the [`DiracDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta.html) function:

Canonicalize arguments:

```
FunctionExpand[DiracDelta[x^5 - 1]]
1/5 DiracDelta[-1 + x]
```

That can be easily applied for this case.

The Green's function has to have a Kernel over which there is to integrate, the hidden variable and domain K[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53677/ulrich-neumann) and K[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Bm7.png) are essential!

The gross result of all the impulses is a doubling of the amplitude towards Infinity for `k`. There is a great problem representing this result for large k in the Plot function because many plot points need to be calculated.

The series without the DiracDelta converges rapidly towards 2. Five summands are well already. So the ten shown in this presentation are already very close to the infinite series.

Comment: Thank you for your work. Indeed, "There is a great problem representing this result for large k in the Plot function because many plot points need to be calculated". This is not it. The Ulrich Neumann's result can be applied for big x, e.g. `Sin[1000.1] + NSum[G[1000.1, 2^n]/2^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]` produces `0.385956`, your result can't. Hope you feel the difference.

Comment: I wonder the upvoter. As it's explained in my comment, this is not it. The road to hell is paved with good intentions.

Answer (score 4):

Correct symbolic solution has already been given in the comment and answers, I'd like to show why your second attempt gives the incorrect result. What you've actually obtained is:

```
Sin[1.1]
(* 0.891207 *)
```

In other words, the summation involving `DiracDelta` doesn't contribute to the numeric solution at all.

So, why does this happen? Well, though there do exist exceptions, a rule of thumb is, *Mathematica* won't be able to handle problem not mentioned in corresponding document. There's no example about handling unevaluated `Sum` in the document of `DSolve`, thus it's not surprising to see the first attempt fails. (I think `DSolve` should have at least returned unevaluated in the first example, though. )

The second attempt is similar. Reading the document of `Integrate`, there's no example about unevaluated `Sum`, and indeed, `Sum` and `Integrate` are still there after `s = r /. k -> Infinity;`. However, *Mathematica* gives an answer after `N[(y[x] /. s) /. x -> 1.1]`, the reason is mentioned in the **Details and Options** section of document of `Integrate`:

> You can get a numerical result by applying `N` to a definite integral. … This effectively calls `NIntegrate`.

and **Possible Issues** section of `DiracDelta`:

> Numerical routines will typically miss the contributions from measures at single points:
>
> ```
> NIntegrate[DiracDelta[x], {x, -2, 1}]
> (* NIntegrate::izero *)
> (* 0. *)
> ```

To sum up: `NIntegrate` is called to handle the unevaluated `Sum` in the last step, but `NIntegrate` can't handle `DiracDelta` properly and the integration evaluates to `0.`, `0.891207` is just the contribution of `Sin[1.1]`.

BTW, another way to find the symbolic solution:

```
Clear[sum]
Integrate[sum[a_], rest_] ^:= sum@Integrate[a, rest]
coef_ sum[a_] ^:= sum[coef a]
sum[a_] + sum[b_] ^:= sum[a + b]

If[$VersionNumber < 10, Activate = Identity];

solrule = Assuming[{n >= 0, x > -Pi/2}, 
  FullSimplify@
      First@DSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] == f[x], y[-Pi/2] == -1, y'[-Pi/2] == 0}, y[x], 
        x] /. -Integrate[expr_, {v_, b_, a_}] + Integrate[expr_, {v_, b_, c_}] :> 
      Integrate[expr, {v, a, c}] /. f -> Function[x, DiracDelta[x - 2^n]/2^n // sum] // 
   FullSimplify]

(*
{y[x] -> Sin[x] + sum[-2^-n HeavisideTheta[-2^n + x] Sin[2^n - x]]}
*)

Hold[sol[x_] := y[x]] /. solrule /. sum[a_] :> NSum[a, {n, 0, Infinity}] // ReleaseHold

sol[1.1]
(* 0.991041 *)
```

Comment: +1. You saw the heart of the problem.  I'd like to comment the quote "Numerical routines will typically miss the contributions from measures at single points" from the documentation: the $\delta$- distribution is not an atomic measure.

Comment: @user64494 Oh, honestly speaking I know almost nothing about measure. Do you mean the wording of document is improper? If so, you may report it to WRI. BTW, It's quoted from document of `DiracDelta`, I made a copy-paste mistake.

Comment: Yes, I do mean the wording of the documentation is improper. That was reported in this forum  several times.